# SQL Join Returning 0 Rows on Basic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am literally losing my mind over this. I have two tables that I am doing tests against from Microsoft's AdventureWorks and there is NO reason this should be happening. They are the Person.Person and Person.BusinessEntityContact and are being matched on with this query:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
USE AdventureWorks2017

SELECT 
Person.Person.BusinessEntityID,
Person.Person.PersonType,
Person.Person.NameStyle,
Person.Person.Title,
Person.Person.FirstName,
Person.Person.MiddleName,
Person.Person.LastName,
Person.Person.Suffix,
Person.Person.EmailPromotion,
Person.Person.AdditionalContactInfo,
Person.Person.Demographics,
Person.Person.rowguid,
Person.Person.ModifiedDate,
Person.BusinessEntityContact.BusinessEntityID,
Person.BusinessEntityContact.PersonID,
Person.BusinessEntityContact.ContactTypeID,
Person.BusinessEntityContact.rowguid,
Person.BusinessEntityContact.ModifiedDate
FROM 
Person.Person
JOIN
Person.BusinessEntityContact
ON
Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntityContact.BusinessEntityID
```

This should return at least something but this is all I get:

[image]

What is going on here to where this even is happening? This is stupid to even have to ask this question on here because this stupidly triggers the moderators or other people do, but this is seriously idiotic that this isn't even working. If someone can do this same query and get a result let me know because something is wrong with my computer or something else if it returns for you.

Comment: Maybe you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`? How many rows does each table have? Is there any matching rows?

Comment: @TheImpaler, yes they do match, are both of type int, and despite the difference of the row now that shouldn't matter. since the purpose is to return the selected column values from the rows where there is a match. I shouldn't have to do a left or right join, and I don't want to return all the rows from either one anyway with null references. According to W3 this should work:

"The INNER JOIN selects all rows from both participating tables as long as there is a match between the columns. An SQL INNER JOIN is same as JOIN clause, combining rows from two or more tables."

Comment: @TheImpaler,the BusinessEntityContact table has fewer rows than the other one but that shouldn't matter. The way I understand an inner join is like this: 

I have two tables that share one column with one having more, less, or equal number of rows. If I want to join these tables to link values from both I will join on that column. Wherever table has the least number of rows has whichever row that matches the other table's rows duplicated to match it's length and returns only those rows that have that match.

Comment: @TheImpaler, a left join on the lesser table would return only the first set that matches the length of the lesser table's rows' length while the right join in the same situation would return all rows in the right side which is the length I need but gives me unnecessary rows that do not match and are nulled out if there isn't a match. It may be my understanding of the parser is different than it actually works but this is basic.

Comment: @AndrewRamshaw . . . I would guess that one of the tables is empty.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, neither of them are but this result is still happening. Any other join works except for this one, and when I'm using the ERP at my job this join works. I was having issues with it and running some tests in SSMS and this is what happened. Do you have much experience with SQL?

Comment: This always happens at the most inopportune time, and I've been trying to figure out why and weirdly enough have come across the weirdest explanations as to how/why weird result sets can occur, but if my understanding is true, then there is no reason for that stuff to be happening. Even with FULL JOINS the overall result set is larger than the max number of rows for the longest table when that should only mean in my mind that matches and nonmatches from both tables are returned which is why the result set is so large and its rarely used. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is what I hate: that the basic logic of the situation can sometimes be interrupted to where you second-guess yourself and the underlying fundamentals of your knowledge about a thing, Being a developer, you already know that things can be understood tens of ways which is why you ask clarifying questions, but when it is as ridiculous as this to where something this simple cannot be done and you start second guessing the parser it's just pathetic and you schizophrenically go about trying to figure out why or how this stuff could possibly occur when it could be a weird glitch waste of time.

Comment: I know it's frustrating when stuff doesn't work as expected but you nearly always find that there is something you didn't consider. To find that something, you need to break the problem into pieces. For example, pick and id that you think should join and run it independently: `SELECT * FROM Person.Person WHERE Person.Person.BusinessEntityID  = 101` and `SELECT * FROM Person.Person WHERE Person.BusinessEntityContact.BusinessEntityID  = 101`. If you do get rows for both of those then you can start looking elsewhere.

Comment: Another way to approach this is to create a 'repro' that someone else can try. Often when building a repro, the act of extracting and reproducing the issue actually uncovers the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't wrong and the setup was just being retarded. I decided to do the exact same thing with another set of tables that shared the same column and it did the returns as normal with all conditions being the same. There was no reason for any of it: character type, length, syntax and dot notation. All of it was the same and it worked for some reason.

```
Use AdventureWorks2017

SELECT 
       Person.Person.BusinessEntityID
      ,Person.Person.PersonType
      ,Person.Person.NameStyle
      ,Person.Person.Title
      ,Person.Person.FirstName
      ,Person.Person.MiddleName
      ,Person.Person.LastName
      ,Person.Person.Suffix
      ,Person.Person.EmailPromotion
      ,Person.Person.AdditionalContactInfo
      ,Person.Person.Demographics
      ,Person.Person.rowguid
      ,Person.Person.ModifiedDate
      ,Person.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID
      ,Person.BusinessEntity.rowguid
      ,Person.BusinessEntity.ModifiedDate
  FROM 
  Person.Person
  INNER JOIN
  Person.BusinessEntity
  ON Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID
```

[image]

This is the exact same query with just a different table and it works.